# Get all 32 bits in an Integer into String format In Clojure

Tags: clojure

I need to get all 32 bits of an Integer in Clojure into String format.

Current: (Integer/toBinaryString 10) -> "1010"

Desired: (Integer/toBinaryString 10) -> "0000000000001010"

How can I do this easily and efficiently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For unsigned integers, you could use `clojure.pprint/cl-format` directly. This example formats `n` as a binary string of at least 32 characters, left padded with `0` characters:

```clj
(require '[clojure.pprint :as pp])

(defn unsigned-binary-32 [n]
  (pp/cl-format nil "~32,'0B" n))
```

For signed integers there is a little more required:

```clj
(defn signed-binary-32 [n]
  (unsigned-binary-32 (bit-and n 0xffffffff)))
```

Answer (score 3):

or you could use classic java approach:

```
user> (clojure.string/replace
       (format "%32s" (Long/toBinaryString 12345))
       \space  \0)
;;=> "00000000000000000011000000111001"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

@leetwinski makes an excellent point!  Here is an even easier version (for positive numbers only!):

```
(defn int->binary-str-32
  [arg]
  (str/pad-left
    (Long/toBinaryString arg) ; convert int to string
    32  ; pad width
    \0  ; pad char
    ))

(int->binary-str-32 12345) => "00000000000000000011000000111001"
```

---

**Original Answer**

[The Tupelo Library has a function](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.03.25/api/tupelo.bits#long-%3Ebits-unsigned) you can use.  Here is an example using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [tupelo.bits :as bits ]
    ))

(defn int->binary-str-32
  [arg]
  (str/join
    (mapv bits/bit->char
      (take-last 32
        (bits/long->bits-unsigned arg)))))
```

with result:

```
(int->binary-str-32 5)                  => "00000000000000000000000000000101"
(int->binary-str-32 Short/MAX_VALUE)    => "00000000000000000111111111111111"
(int->binary-str-32 Integer/MAX_VALUE)  => "01111111111111111111111111111111"
```

This only works on non-negative values (negative values are left as an exercise for the reader).

Or you can modify the [original source code](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/v21.03.25/src/clj/tupelo/bits.clj#L32).